# Why can't I see radio button when I check cookie?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I was try to post from Ajax to PHP file to build poll system but I can't send any request because I can't see radio button...Something wrong with cookie check...what I just want to check user IP if he already vote disappear radio buttons, if not he display radio buttons

index.html

> ```
>     <script type="text/javascript" >
>         $(function(){
>             var loader=$('#loader');
>             var pollcontainer=$('#pollcontainer');
>             loader.fadeIn();
>             //Load the poll form
>             $.get('poll.php', '', function(data, status){
>                 pollcontainer.html(data);
>                 animateResults(pollcontainer);
>                 pollcontainer.find('#viewresult').click(function(){
>                     //if user wants to see result
>                     loader.fadeIn();
>                     $.get('poll.php', 'result=1', function(data,status){
>                         pollcontainer.fadeOut(1000, function(){
>                             $(this).html(data);
>                             animateResults(this);
>                         });
>                         loader.fadeOut();
>                     });
>                     //prevent default behavior
>                     return false;
>                 }).end()
>                 .find('#pollform').submit(function(){
>                     var selected_val=$(this).find('input[name=poll]:checked').val();
>                     if(selected_val!=''){
>                         //post data only if a value is selected
>                         loader.fadeIn();
>                         $.post('poll.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data, status){
>                             $('#formcontainer').fadeOut(100, function(){
>                                 $(this).html(data);
>                                 animateResults(this);
>                                 loader.fadeOut();
>                             });
>                         });
>                     }
>                     //prevent form default behavior
>                     return false;
>                 });
>                 loader.fadeOut();
>             });
>
>             function animateResults(data){
>                 $(data).find('.bar').hide().end().fadeIn('slow', function(){
>                     $(this).find('.bar').each(function(){
>                         var bar_width=$(this).css('width');
>                         $(this).css('width', '0').animate({ width: bar_width }, 1000);
>                     });
>                 });
>             }
>
>         });
>     </script>
> ```

poll.php

```
if (!isset($_POST['poll']) || !isset($_POST['pollid'])) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, ques FROM questions ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        //display question
        echo "<p class=\"pollques\" >" . $row['ques'] . "</p>";
        $poll_id = $row['id'];
    }
    if (isset($_GET["result"]) == 1 || isset($_COOKIE["voted" . $poll_id]) == 'yes') {
        //if already voted or asked for result
        showresults($poll_id);
        exit;
    } else {
        //display options with radio buttons
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, value FROM options WHERE ques_id=$poll_id");
        if (mysql_num_rows($query)) {
            echo '<div id="formcontainer" ><form method="post" id="pollform" action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" >';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="pollid" value="' . $poll_id . '" />';
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                echo '<p><input type="radio" name="poll" value="' . $row['id'] . '" id="option-' . $row['id'] . '" /> 
                <label for="option-' . $row['id'] . '" >' . $row['value'] . '</label></p>';
            }
            echo '<p><input type="submit"  value="Submit" /></p></form>';
            echo '<p><a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?result=1" id="viewresult">View result</a></p></div>';
        }
    }
} else {
    // i cant see this radio 
    if (isset($_COOKIE["voted" . $_POST['pollid']]) != 'yes') {

        //Check if selected option value is there in database?
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM options WHERE id='" . intval($_POST["poll"]) . "'");
        if (mysql_num_rows($query)) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO votes(option_id, voted_on, ip) VALUES('" . $_POST["poll"] . "', '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "', '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "')";
            if (mysql_query($query)) {
                //Vote added to database
                setcookie("voted" . $_POST['pollid'], 'yes', time() + 86400 * 300);
            }
            else
                echo "There was some error processing the query: " . mysql_error();
        }
    }
    showresults(intval($_POST['pollid']));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isset($_COOKIE["voted" . $poll_id]) == 'yes'` isset returns true or false, so this condition is always false.
same with this `if (isset($_COOKIE["voted" . $_POST['pollid']]) != 'yes')`